# Improve postgres v9.4 SQL return table function for postgres v13

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

We are in the process of migrating from PostgreSQL v9.4 to v13. In doing so we have to migrate all our functions too, The following FUNCTION issue a 42704 error stating that
**record_type** cannot be found in either prod or public. This function worked in v9.4 but when I copy the FUNCTION sql below and input it in Pgadmin4 in v13 to duplicate the function, I receive **ERROR 42704**. A Visual Basic .NET application calls this function so I prefer to tweak it *only* enough so it loads in v13 and works in a similar manner.

This function takes three arguments
tablename - the name of the table being queried
selectcols - a comma-separated list of the cols to be selected
clause - a spatial clause to query the table spatially

As a novice to postgresql FUNCTIONS, I believe the issue is the variable record_type
as it's not used elsewhere in the function. I have seen the following syntax:

```
SELECT * INTO record_type FROM tablename WERE clause
```

The function below does not employ that syntax and I was wondering if that's a possible way to fix this. Additionally, I have read to avoid using **SETOF** as this is obsolete syntax.

Just looking for a suggestion/example of how to rectify the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prod._fsearchaa(
             tablename character varying DEFAULT::NULL character varying, 
             selectcols text DEFAULT NULL::text, 
             clause text DEFAULT NULL::text)
RETURNS SETOF record_type AS
$BODY$
   DECLARE SQL text DEFAULT NULL;
           r record;
BEGIN
     SQL := ' SELECT ' || selectcols || ' FROM ' || tablename || ' WHERE ' || clause AS sql;
     FOR r in EXECUTE sql LOOP
         RETURN NEXT r;
     END LOOP;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
COST 100;
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION prod.fsearchaa(character varying, text, text) SET search_path=prod,public;
ALTER FUNCTION prod.fsearchaa(character varying, text, text)
    OWNER TO dbuser;
```

I modified the above to be and this appears to work without specifying **SETOF record_type**.I'm still curious if anyone would have additional input. The modified proc is as follows:

*Col1,Co12,Col3* are found in the table that is passed in as `tablename`. Hard coding the column names makes the proc more rigid. I like the idea of passing in `selectcols` which would equate to "column_id_1, column_id_2, column_id_3". Not sure if I could split the `selectcols` with the "." delimiter and add that to the **RETURN TABLE** clause near the beginning of the FUNCTION.

CHANGE:

I am still focuses on getting this proc to work with *any* input tablename and any set of corresponding columns associated with that table coupled with a spatial string.

I attemped to use the **anyelement** clause for the input tablename.
The reason being is that I keep receiving an error on the **SETOF <variable_name> AS** shown above in the original code.  The changes below allowed me to at least save the function in the schema Functions repository. However when i extecute the function as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM prod._fsearchaa(<tablename>, <columns>, <spatial_clause>)
```

**I receive the **ERROR: could determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown (42804)**. The function I am now test with the polymorphic dynamic argument is as follows. I have highlighted all the places I use anyelement in the function below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prod._fsearchaa(
             tablename **anyelement**, 
             selectcols text DEFAULT NULL::text, 
             clause text DEFAULT NULL::text)
RETURNS SETOF **anyelement** AS
$BODY$
   DECLARE SQL text DEFAULT NULL;
           r record;
BEGIN
     SQL := ' SELECT ' || selectcols || ' FROM ' || tablename || ' WHERE ' || clause AS sql;
     FOR r in EXECUTE sql LOOP
         RETURN NEXT r;
     END LOOP;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
COST 100;
ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION prod.fsearchaa(**anyelement**, text, text) SET search_path=prod,public;
ALTER FUNCTION prod.fsearchaa(**anyelement**, text, text)
    OWNER TO dbuser;
```

Comment: The issue is this `...SETOF record_type...`. `record_type` needs to be an existing type from either `CREATE TYPE` or the composite type that is associated with each table. I am going to say you have not included that type in the v13 instance so it is not being found. Or the [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) is not correctly set to find `record_type` in whatever schema it resides in.

Comment: Klaver Response: Thank oyu! I have ensured that the search path is set  for the user (dbuser) using ALTER ROLE in the users group to be "search_path = prod,public".  So as far as I know that should be fine. In v9.4 I never had to actually create the table record_type in advance. record_type is local to this function its not an actual table in either prod or public. This what is being returned to the VB NET application.

Comment: "DEFAULT::NULL" is not legal syntax in either version.

Comment: @jjanes, it may not be legal but it works.

Comment: @user9491577. It does not have to be a table, it just needs to be a `type`.   `SETOF` has to point at a `type` that exists outside the function. In the 9.4 instance in `psql` I'm betting if you do `\dT` you will see `record_type`.  `RETURNS TABLE` is just building a `type` on the fly.  FYI,  tables in Postgres have a composite type associated with them per [Row types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html): "Whenever you create a table, a composite type is also automatically created, with the same name as the table, to represent the table's row type."

Comment: @AdrianKlaver  For me it gives a syntax pointing to that location in both versions, before it has a chance to complain about the return type.

Comment: A [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ZXVCDRJ8eCVHnsFWaUtpk/1) that works. I had to use `'` instead of `$$` as dbfiddle was having problems with dollar quoting. On my machine in both Postgres 12 & 14 it works with either `'` or `$$`.